# Do request to some site with angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have some service in my project.
user.service.t.js
I would like to get request to some site e.g. sites.com and get the content of site. I do it the way, which has wrote the below.

```
getSites(user) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
   var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      url: "http://www.joomag.com/",
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials: true
    })

    return this.http.post("http://www.sites.com/", <RequestOptionsArgs> {withCredentials: true, headers: headers})
      .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
          return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
        }
      });

  }
```

However, I get this error:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.sites.com/. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null.
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

These headers are meaningless on client requests. They need to be added on the server response. If they are not added on the response by the server, the browser throws this error.

You can try with `JsonpModule` instead of `HttpModule` but you can't add `withCredentials` option there (don't know if you actually need it).

Comment: When I use express server to do request to remote site it is work fine. Now I would like to to request via service angular2. When I use jsonp it isn't work for me.

Comment: This is CORS and it's a browser feature, therefore you won't experience anything like this if you send the request from a server. Either you can make the server to send the required headers or you can use JSONP which has quite some limitations (no custom headers), otherwise you're out of luck. An alternative approach is to make a request to your own server and forward the request from your server to the server you actually want to contact (because as mentioned CORS affects only browsers).